# Type 'Observable<{} | GeneralSettings>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<GeneralSettings>'

Tags: angular

I got this error:

```
Type 'Observable<{} | GeneralSettings>' is not assignable to type 'GeneralSettings | Observable<GeneralSettings> | Promise<GeneralSettings>'.
Type 'Observable<{} | GeneralSettings>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<GeneralSettings>'.
Type '{} | GeneralSettings' is not assignable to type 'GeneralSettings'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'GeneralSettings'.
Property 'address' is missing in type '{}'.
Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.
```

This is my code:

```
 import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
 import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
 import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
 import { GeneralSettings } from "../../../../models/generalSettings";
 import { GeneralSettingsService } from "../../../../_services/apis/general-settings.service";

 @Injectable()
 export class GeneralSettingsResolver implements Resolve<GeneralSettings> {

 constructor(private api: GeneralSettingsService) {
 }


 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<GeneralSettings> | Promise<GeneralSettings> | GeneralSettings {

    return this.api.get("/") //fineOne
        .catch(() => {
            return Observable.empty<GeneralSettings>()
        });
 } 
 }
```

What's wrong in this?
I'm new to Angular, and I have only tried to run this project, but it doesn't run!

Comment: try `import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty' `

Comment: what version of rxjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using a version of rxjs < 6 then you can use the `empty()` function as this :

```
 import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
 import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
 import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
 import { GeneralSettings } from "../../../../models/generalSettings";
 import { GeneralSettingsService } from "../../../../_services/apis/general-settings.service";

 @Injectable()
 export class GeneralSettingsResolver implements Resolve<GeneralSettings> {

 constructor(private api: GeneralSettingsService) {
 }


 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<{} | GeneralSettings> | Promise<GeneralSettings> | GeneralSettings  {

    return this.api.get("/") //fineOne
        .catch(() => {
            return Observable.empty()
        });
    } 
 }
```